# NHibernate ICompositeUserType split string columns

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I would implement an ICompositeUserType for a string property, that is splitted in 4 columns of 2000 chars (in a legacy oracle database, to avoid CLOB/LONG fields). 
Implementing the interface seems to be a good idea, but I can't understand the SetPropertyValue method. It doesn't accepts typed or string values. And I need it as mutable, so I need to implement this method.

I could have a non persistent property that encapsulates the split and join to x persitent properties, but I want something more transparent.

I've found similar questions but none responses as I expected.

-- UPDATE--

I upload some code to add context to the question:

DATABASE:

```
...
Value VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE)
Value2 VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE)
Value3 VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE)
Value4 VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE)
Value5 VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE)
...
```

HBM:

```
<property name="Value" type="MyAssembly.NHibernateUtils.Types.MultiColumnJoinedUserType, MyAssembly">
  <column name="DFM_Value"/>
  <column name="DFM_Value2"/>
  <column name="DFM_Value3"/>
  <column name="DFM_Value4"/>
  <column name="DFM_Value5"/>
</property>
```

CLASS:

```
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
```

MultiColumnJoinedUserType:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Set the value of a property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="component">an instance of class mapped by this "type"</param>
    /// <param name="property"></param>
    /// <param name="value">the value to set</param>
    public void SetPropertyValue(object component, int property, object value) { ... }
```

In my class the component field of the method is a string, so it's impossible to change its value without changing the reference, because string is passed as value not as reference as I need.

Comment: Have you tried NullSafeSet instead of SetPropertyValue?

Comment: Is an interface, I must implement all methods, NullSafeSet is working fine!

Comment: How can your string be mutable ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spend some hours in this issue and various solutions tried:

- Use a string[] instead of a string in a ICompositeUserType
- Use a IUserType instead of a ICompositeUserType

Both worked in Oracle, but in SQL (I need the compatibility) the null values are set as default insted of null.

NHibernate trace in log4net:

```
INSERT INTO VALUETABLE (HDF_Value1, HDF_Value2, HDF_Value3, HDF_Value4, HDF_Value5) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5); select SCOPE_IDENTITY(); @p1 = NULL [Type: String (4000)], @p2 = NULL [Type: String (4000)], @p3 = NULL [Type: String (4000)], @p4 = NULL [Type: String (4000)], @p5 = NULL [Type: String (4000)]
```

But in SQLProfiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO VALUETABLE (HDF_Value1, HDF_Value2, HDF_Value3, HDF_Value4, HDF_Value5) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()',N'@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 nvarchar(4000),@p4 nvarchar(4000),@p5 nvarchar(4000)',@p1=default,@p2=default,@p3=default,@p4=default,@p5=default
```

I've tried various pieces of code on nullsafeset (use DBNull, string.NullSafeSet, ...) but nothing works for me. I can't waste more time and finally I've implemented the simplest solution, 5 "hidden" properties on mapped object and a "virtual" property that splits and joins the values, it isn't very transparent but it works as expected:

```
    public virtual string _Value1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string _Value2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string _Value3 { get; set; }
    public virtual string _Value4 { get; set; }
    public virtual string _Value5 { get; set; }

    public virtual string Value
    {
        get
        {
            // JOIN VALUES FROM 5 _Value properties
        }
        set
        {
            // SPLIT VALUE INTO 5 _Value properties
        }
    }
```

That's enough for me in this moment.

Answer (score 1):

The `ICompositeUserType` is typically for when you have multiple properties in .Net (e.g. a "component"). There is an example for a `Money` class here: http://geekswithblogs.net/opiesblog/archive/2006/08/05/87218.aspx

Since you have just a single simple value in .Net, you should implement `IUserType` instead, which will still allow you to use multiple columns in the database.

Comment: No, as I understand, ICompositeUserType is for multiple columns on database to one property in .net

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my sentence is not accurate (excuse my poor english), but Money is a single property of the mapped object. And yes, I read the sample two days ago, when I started to fix that problem, but it didn't applies with my issue. Money is an object and it's passed as reference and in the sample is marked as immutable and the SetPropertyValue throws an Exception. Watcy my post update with some code to understand better.

Comment: My point is that the Money-type itself is the "composite" - it has multiple properties, and using the ICompositeUserType allows referencing those individual properties inside HQL queries (e.g NH will understand `"... transaction.TheMoney.Amount > 1000 ..."`. The ICompositeUserType should work, but since you have a simple string property the IUserType, which can also handle multiple columns, should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I've tried to use an IUserType and seems to work all fine, but at last, in sql (in oracle works fine) the null string values are setted as "default" instead of null and it throws an SQLException:"(0x80131904) The parameterized query ... expects the parameter '@xxx', which was not supplied", in NHibernate log4net trace it shows as null (@xxx=NULL), but in SQLProfiler it shows as default: @xxx=default... bffff!

Comment: Have you remembered to use DbNull.Value towards the database?

Comment: Yes, I explain in detail in the answer below.

Comment: Hmm... 'default'... what was the actual value that ended up in the database table? Haven't really seen that before.

Comment: No value is set cause the INSERT sentence throws the exception (0x80131904) The parameterized query ... expects the parameter '@xxx', which was not supplied"

Comment: It's great that you solved the problem using a different solution, but out of curiosity, would you mind posting the IUserType implementation you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The string is not mutable. You can safely ignore `SetPropertyValue`. I've implemented `GetPropertyValue` in my immutable user types, I think it gets called.

```
    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void SetPropertyValue(object component, int property, object value)
    {
      throw new NotSupportedException("Something goes wrong here");
    }


    public object GetPropertyValue(object component, int property)
    {
      var stringComponent = (string)component;
      maxLengthToRead = Math.Min(2000, stringComponent.Length - property * 2000);
      if (maxLengthToRead <= 0) return string.Empty;

      return stringComponent.Substring(property * 2000, maxLengthToRead);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but due to a legacy code, we're using Session.Merge and it calls SetPropertyValue for the type. The problem is solved using IUserType instead of ICompositeUserType as points Oskar in its response.